# Popup window open in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, shell, internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to open a popup window when a user clicks on a certain link. However, I am stuck and I am trying to open this popup window only using Internet Explorer if a user is in edge or Chrome. I have tried the below code, but I can't seem to figure it out where is it failing.  Could there be a way to programmatically accomplish this? Any help will be extremely appreciated.

```
  <a href="google.com" onclick="return popUpWin('popwin.html')"
        >PopUp Window Clickme</a>
<script>
function popUpWin(link) {
        newwindow=window.open(link,'name','height=300,width=170');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    } 

Function Openlink() 

{
var shell = new ActiveXObject ("WSCRIPT.Shell")
shell.run("iexplorer.exe http://goole.com")
console.log("Testing")
}
```

Comment: the correct program name for internet explorer is `iexplore.exe` as a starting point...

Answer (score 0):

```
shell.run("iexplorer.exe http://goole.com")
```

This will not open internet explorer

Also, make sure popups are enabled on Chrome & Edge.
Chrome and Edge are much more secure.